# How to I derive the potential from a homogeneous time dependent electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

As the title says how can I derive the potential $V(t)$ from the following electric field given as
$$
E(t) = \frac{A}{\sqrt{\pi}\tau}e^{-(\frac{t}{\tau})^2}
$$
Where $A$ and $\tau$ are constants.

Comment: The time dependence does not make a difference. The electric field should be a vector though, are you missing something?

Comment: Yes I'm also confused why the e-field is not a vector. But In my problem that is stated says that I have a charge particle in linear harmonic oscillator, if that is to any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link between elecrostatic field and potential is

$$ \mathbf{E} = - \nabla V = -(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\mathbf{u_x} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\mathbf{u_y} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\mathbf{u_z})$$

You only gave one component of $\mathbf{E}$, or $\|\mathbf{E}\|$, so I'll assume that $\mathbf{E} = E(t) \mathbf{u_x}$. Then, you know that

$$\begin{cases}
    \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = -E(t) \\
    \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} = 0 \\
    \frac{\partial V}{\partial z} = 0
\end{cases}$$

So $$V = -E(t)x + A(y,z) + B(x,z) + C(x, y) $$

where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are arbitrarly chosen.

Comment: Great answer but I think $A$, $B$ and $C$ is zero.

Comment: @user2120387 What functions $f$ verifie $f' = g$, with $g$ another function?